# Ask for a variable defined in renderer from preload

Tags: node.js, electron

With:

- contextIsolation = true
- nodeIntegration = false

What is the best way to ask for the value of a variable defined in the renderer context from preload context?

I'm developing an application for managing photo collections.

In my main.js there is a menuItem to import photos, the click function for this menu entry is:

```
click() {
  dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
    title: 'Import',
    properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.filePaths.length) {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('import', result.filePaths);
    }
  });
}
```

in preload.js:

```
ipcRenderer.on('import', (ev, origins) => {
  origins.forEach(origin => {
    files.importPhoto(origin, dir);
  });
});
```

the 'dir' attribute in preload function is the destination folder to copy the photos and is the value I need to get from the app.js in the renderer.

Comment: i normally put the `ipcRenderer` in the renderer page, not in the `preload`. I just found code in the preload doesn't persist well. And in the doc, `ipcRenderer` is designed for the renderer.

Comment: But without nodeintegration, you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify `dir` in your preload.js file, you should expose your `ipcRenderer.on` code as a function through the contextBridge. Ie.

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api",
    {
        importFunc: function(dir) {
            // clear out any existing listeners if this method
            // is called multiple times from the app.js/renderer code
            ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("import");

            ipcRenderer.on("import", (ev, origins) => {
                origins.forEach(origin => {
                    files.importPhoto(origin, dir);
                });
            });
        }
    }
)
```

In your app.js/renderer code, you could call this function like so when you have the right value for `dir`. (Once this method is run, your MenuItem click should pull in the right value).

```js
window.api.importFunc("C:\\myfolder");
```